# How can I find a way to write an application do download YouTube videos?

Tags: video, youtube, download, download-manager

I have no programming knowledge and I don't know how to code but for some reasons I would love to learn to create a YouTube video download manager with my own customization. So I need your help on how and using what tools and programming\scripting languages I'm able to learn how to do that. Some points I'm considering:

- I love to work on GUI. I mean I want to make it eye-pleasing
- It would be better if the application be web-based. that is the application runs through web browsers but it is able to download youtube videos on your hard drive. also you can change it's setting 
  through web browsers
- It would also be alright if it be a windows-based program

So what are my choices? By the use of what tools am I able to achieve such thing? Is it going to be difficult (you know because I don't know anything about programming and it will probably take some time to cover the basics).

Can you recommend me some guides on that too? Please suggest some easy tools so that I'll be able to make head or tail of them. something easy to learn and use and of course practical for the purpose of creating a YouTube video download manager. 
I'm looking forward to your help and suggestions. Please recommend me the best tools for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to just produce an application to manage downloads with no technical component using at least some code. There are tutorials to help learn basics on YouTube and [this](http://www.ngcoders.com/php-script/php-youtube-video-downloader-script/) is a good tutorial for PHP, check the source code to help you learn.

[Here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-youtube-downloader-using-c/26801) is also a good one for C# which is easy to follow.